# malware identification found on ubuntu server

Tags: perl, malware

I discovered a script running on my server. Reading through apache log files, attacker used cms login vulnerability and downloaded script from this site `http://217.61.107.9/wes`. Can anybody identify what does it do? After hitting `htop` I could see:

```
sh -c chmod 777 sysd && ./sysd -c 2.cf
```

which is now gone ang all I can see is remaining process

```
./sysd -c apache.cf -t 1
```

This I can not find on server so I have no idea what does it do. Cpu is normal. Thank you

Comment: @jsotola it is a simple text file, here you go https://pastebin.com/qGTy6Qb2

Comment: It appears to be a DDOS client, used in distributed attacks for overloading other machines. You have a compromised server and you are helping in malicious behaviour (against your will). Take it down and rebuild it. See also [How to deal with a compromised server](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) at ServerFault.